# PHP counting numbers from POST with comma as decimal

Tags: php

I have a POST from. User types for ex. 2,5... I need to transfrom 2,5 into 2.5 (to make it suitable for forward calculating)... 
I use:

```
$eddited_input = str_replace(',', '.', $input);
```

It works, but when I chech the results, they aren't correct... Can anybody help me?

Here is the full code:

```
if($typ_vypoctu == 1){
    $pocatecni_castka = $_POST["pocatecni_castka"];
    urokova_sazba = $_POST["urokova_sazba"];
    $frekvence_uroceni = $_POST["frekvence_uroceni"];
    $doba_uroceni = $_POST["doba_uroceni"];
    $upravena_castka = str_replace(',', '.', $pocatecni_castka);
    $upravena_sazba = str_replace(',', '.', $urokova_sazba);
    $upravena_doba = str_replace(',', '.', $doba_uroceni);
    if(!empty($pocatecni_castka) AND !empty($urokova_sazba) AND !empty($frekvence_uroceni) AND !empty($doba_uroceni)){
        if(is_numeric($upravena_castka) AND is_numeric($upravena_sazba) AND is_numeric($upravena_doba)){
            $urocitel = (1 + ($urokova_sazba / (100 * $frekvence_uroceni)));
            $mocnina = $upravena_doba * $frekvence_uroceni;
            $mocnina_urocitele = pow($urocitel, $mocnina);
            $vysledek = $mocnina_urocitele * $upravena_castka;
            $zaokrouhleni_vysledku = round($vysledek, 0);
            $hezky_vysledek = oddeleni_null($zaokrouhleni_vysledku);
            $jednoduche = round($pocatecni_castka * (1 + (($upravena_sazba / 100) * $upravena_doba)), 0);
            $rozdil = $zaokrouhleni_vysledku - $jednoduche; 
            echo "<table class='table'>";
            echo "<tr><td><h4><b>Konečná částka: </b></h4></td><td><h4>" . $hezky_vysledek . " Kč</h4></td></tr>";
            if($rozdil > 0){
                echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>V případě jednoduchého úročnení by konečná částka byla " . oddeleni_null($jednoduche) . " Kč, to je o <font color='red'>" . oddeleni_null($rozdil) . " Kč</font> méně.</td></tr>";    
            }elseif ($rozdil < 0) {
                echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>V případě jednoduchého úročnení by konečná částka byla " . oddeleni_null($jednoduche) . " Kč, to je o <font color='green'>" . oddeleni_null($rozdil - (2 * $rozdil)) . " Kč</font> více.</td></tr>";  
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }else{
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><b>Upozornění:</b> Hodnoty musí být zadány číselně!</div>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><b>Upozornění:</b> Všechna pole jsou povinná!</div>";
    }


}
```

Comment: *How* are he results not correct?

Comment: The result is supposed to be 131 141 Kč with "úrok" 2,5, but it says 110 408 Kč and when I type the value of "úrok" with dot (2.5), it works fine...

Comment: Could You create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. To replace a string with another string in the same variable , you must  make a modification in the same variable in which you are storing your string.

```
$new="My name is akshay , and i love coding";
$new=str_replace(",",".",$new);
echo $new;
// OUTPUT : My name is akshay . and i love coding
```